# How to find the global catalog of my network in ADDC?

Tags: windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server-2008-x64

I'm learning IT right now, and I have this situation.

The employee who was the administrator, got out of the company. But he doesn't leave a documentation to tell me which of my ADDC (Active Directory Domain Controller) is the PDC, I mean I'm interested to fin the global catalog and structure of my network.

Does you know a post from TechNet or some site to find this PDC in Windows Server 2008 R2?

Answer (score 1):

You can either open Active Directory Sites and services, expand sites -> servers and look at the NTDS settings of each server you have, there will be a tick box on the general tab that will be checked if the server is a global catalog.

Alternatively, if you have quite a lot of servers and don't want to have to do this for each one, you can use nslookup:

[Find a list of global catalogs using nslookup](http://www.websense.com/support/article/kbarticle/How-Do-I-Find-a-List-of-Global-Catalog-Servers-Using-nslookup)

As for PDC though, these haven't really existed since windows NT, there is however a PDC emulator FSMO role which is held by one domain controller that you can find using the following command:

dsquery server -hasfsmo pdc

You can see the other FSMO roles here:

[Identify Operations Master Roles](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc758669%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can display the Global Catalog Servers in the domain you are logged in to using Nslookup.exe:

1. Open a CMD.EXE window.
2. Type the following command and press Enter:

nslookup gc._msdcs.%USERDNSDOMAIN%

Answer (score 0):

Run the following from a command promt:

```
nslookup
set type=serv
_gc._tcp."FQDN"
```